# How can we make our custom PDF editor with our custom editable logics with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3

I want to make a feature using vuejs jsust like MS word to edit PDFs. How can I make such pdf editor with vuejs in which I can add my own customization logic?

e.g.
Feature should be able to do things like

1. Adding conditional replace text
2. Adding tags to text within pdf
3. Change background color of text.

Comment: You would have to be more specific, you could start the project you want and when specific questions arise ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a fairly major project. Perhaps you should look for libraries already built, read through issues on Github and project documentation to get a sense as to how these products are built.

There are only a handful of packages in the 'awesome vuejs' library that deal with PDF viewers. No PDF creators that I can see; it's probably very hard to do.

This one has 1700 stars and is not recently active, meaning there may not be a lot of people actively working on the custom PDF editor space.  This may be the largest in the Vue community for viewing, not editing.
https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf

Take a look at this curated list for inspiration in various UI areas:
https://awesome-vue.js.org/components-and-libraries/ui-components.html#pdf

Best of luck to you,
Marcus